# How can I store some sensitive plugin data on WordPress server?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm building one WordPress plugin and there is a requirement where I need to store some token on the server which will be used to make further API calls.

my question is:
**Does WordPress have any storage API to make sure my data is only available for my plugin and not to others?**

If not, then is there any way to handle such a case.

I did some research but apart from DB and wp option I couldn't find much -and I believe that's accessible to every plugins/OR those who has access to setup.

Note: Data should be available across users